# Cant access some of the object properties when using openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, openweathermap

I am using axios to fetch weather information from openweathermap api in my react application. From the result of the api call (which is a json object), I can access some properties, for example `data.base`. But cant access `data.coord.icon` or `data.weather[0].id` etc.

```
data = [
        coord: { lon: -0.1257,lat: 51.5085},
        weather: [{ id: 721,
                    main: "Haze",
                    description: "haze",
                    icon: "50n"
                  }],
        base: "stations"
      ]
```

I tried all the possible combinations. When trying to return `data.coord`, got the error **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {lon, lat}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead**
But `data.coord.lon` gives **lon of undefined**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class WeatherInfo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        isFetching: false,
        data: [],
    }
}

//function to fetch weather information
async  getWeatherData(lat, lon) {
    const weatherApi = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_KEY}`

    try {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, isFetching: true });
        const response = await axios.get(weatherApi);
        this.setState({ data: response.data, isFetching: false });
        console.log(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ isFetching: false })
    }
}

//function to get access to users location and to call getWeatherData function
weatherInit = () => {

    const success = (position) => {
        this.getWeatherData(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }

    const error = () => {
        alert('Unable to retrieve location.');
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support location tracking, or permission is denied.');
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.weatherInit();
}

render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default WeatherInfo
```

Comment: Can you please `console.log(response.data)` that you getting and show the output here.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: need way more context to even kind of know what you are talking about.

Comment: @NikitaGalibin  coord: {lon: 76.2711, lat: 10.8505}
weather: [{…}]
base: "stations"
main: {temp: 297.15, feels_like: 301.07, temp_min: 297.15, temp_max: 297.15, pressure: 1008, …}
visibility: 1500
wind: {speed: 1.03, deg: 70}
clouds: {all: 75}
dt: 1610131334
sys: {type: 1, id: 9209, country: "IN", sunrise: 1610154958, sunset: 1610196454}
timezone: 19800
id: 1256432
name: "Shōranūr"
cod: 200

Comment: Where are you trying to display it? if possible, please provide code for the whole component.

Comment: @NikitaGalibin the entire component is added. Thanks.

Comment: @Anoop you trying to display the data inside the JSX(render() method) right?

Comment: @NikitaGalibin yes right.

Comment: @Sakshi  The entire component is added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: why is the use of `isFetching` state

Comment: @mirsahib its for the purpose to add loading animations. kindly ignore it in this context. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how you can display various data returned by the API.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class WeatherInfo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isFetching: false,
      data: [],
    }
  }

  //function to fetch weather information
  async getWeatherData(lat, lon) {
    const weatherApi = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_KEY}`

    try {
      this.setState({ ...this.state,
        isFetching: true
      });
      const response = await axios.get(weatherApi);
      if(response.status===200){
            //update state only if status is 200
            this.setState({
                 data: response.data,
                 isFetching: false
            });
      console.log(response.data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({
        isFetching: false
      })
    }
  }

  //function to get access to users location and to call getWeatherData function
  weatherInit = () => {

    const success = (position) => {
      this.getWeatherData(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }

    const error = () => {
      alert('Unable to retrieve location.');
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support location tracking, or permission is denied.');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.weatherInit();
  }

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    
    if (data) {
      return ( 
      <div >
        //display coord
        <p > {data.coord.lon} < /p> 
        <p > {data.coord.lat} < /p>
        // display weather ids
        {data.weather.map(item => {
           return ( 
           < p > { item.id } < /p>) })
         } 
         < p > { data.name } < /p> < / div >
        )
    }
    else {
     return (<div>Data is loading or Not Found</div>)}
    }
   }
 }

  export default WeatherInfo
```

Necessarily you need to create an JSX element for each value you want to display.
Sorry, for formatting.

Comment: Actually I'm getting errors saying that 'lon' is undefined when trying to display `data.coord.lon`. That is why I didn't add more JSX elements. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Anoop that means your data is loaded incorrectly.  I will make an edit to my answer and you can try it again.

Comment: try running `weatherInit()` function asynchronously

Comment: @NikitaGalibin `console.log`  before the return statement gives the result as expected. That means the data is loaded correct, right?